# Python Requests: POST form-data with empty file field

Tags: python, python-requests, multipartform-data

Python 3.x, Requests 2.18.4

Trying to reproduce the following multi-part form-data request in python's requests library

[image: form-data request]

Just need to post the URL, but the other field is required else the sedrver responds with an error.

Doing the following doesn't work

```py
requests.post(target, files={'img[]': ('', '', 'application/octet-stream'),'url': (None, url)})
```

Requests doesn't create a `request.body` when I execute the above. Can't find a way to post the form-data with both fields, without adding a file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Parameter name seem to be `"uri"`, not `"url"`

Comment: My mistake, you're correct. Fixing parameter names doesn't help, however.

Comment: hello @BobsBurgers, I'm facing this same issue, did you ever found out how to pass empty fields in a form using requests?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for the answer to this. the easiest way is to just pass an empty dictionary to the `files` parameter:

```
requests.post(url,..., files={})
```

---

there is also another workaround found here (https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/1081) where you can generate an object of this class and pass it as the content for files:

```
class ForceMultipartDict(dict):
def __bool__(self):
    return True

FORCE_MULTIPART = ForceMultipartDict()  # An empty dict that boolean-evaluates as `True`.


client.post(url, data={"some": "data"}, files=FORCE_MULTIPART)
```

Comment: this is the solution class ForceMultipartDict(dict):
def __bool__(self):
    return True

FORCE_MULTIPART = ForceMultipartDict()  # An empty dict that boolean-evaluates as `True`.


client.post(url, data={"some": "data"}, files=FORCE_MULTIPART) thank you